# separar JSON por elementos en PHP

Tags: php, json, array

Una consulta estoy generando un json en php  en base a un resultado de una API en google, cuando imprimo en pantalla el json me aparece bien pero no me separa por cada resultado el json con coma (,) ej: tengo este resultado del json

```
{"title":"hoy","start":"2020-01-24T10:30:00-05:00","end":"2020-01-24T13:45:00-05:00"}{"title":"hoy2","start":"2020-01-24T15:00:00-05:00","end":"2020-01-24T17:45:00-05:00"}
```

pero necesito lo mismo separado con , al inicio del otro item asi

```
[
  {
    "end": "2020-01-24T13:45:00-05:00",
    "start": "2020-01-24T10:30:00-05:00",
    "title": "hoy"
  },
  {
    "end": "2020-01-24T17:45:00-05:00",
    "start": "2020-01-24T15:00:00-05:00",
    "title": "hoy2"
  }
]
```

agradezco mucho en lo que me puedan guiar

relaciono como estoy imprimiendo el json en php

```php
if (empty($events)) {
    print "No upcoming events found.\n";
} else {
    print "Todos Los Eventos<br>\n";

    foreach ($events as $event) {

        $start = $event->start->dateTime;
        $array=array(
            "title"=>$event->summary,
            "start"=>$event->start->dateTime,
            "end"=>$event->end->dateTime,
        );

        if (empty($start)) {
            $start = $event->start->date;
        }

        echo json_encode($array);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La razón principal, para que salgan de la forma en como mencionas es por que el `echo` esta dentro del `foreach`, entonces cada vez que pase por ahí escribirá el `array` tal cual como describes, entonces una solucion sería lo siguiente

```php
if (empty($events)) {
    print "No upcoming events found.\n";
} else {
    print "Todos Los Eventos<br>\n";
    $arreglo = [];
    foreach ($events as $event) {

        $start = $event->start->dateTime;
        $arreglo[] = array(
            "title"=>$event->summary,
            "start"=>$event->start->dateTime,
            "end"=>$event->end->dateTime,
        );

        if (empty($start)) {
            $start = $event->start->date;
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($arreglo);
}
```

1.- Donde `$arreglo = [];` inicializamos el arreglo.

2.- Asigno un valor al arreglo

```
$arreglo[] = array(
    "title"=>$event->summary,
    "start"=>$event->start->dateTime,
    "end"=>$event->end->dateTime,
);
```

3.- Fuera del `foreach` muestro el contenido de `$arreglo`

Ahora bien queda a tu disposición como vas agregando mas entradas a tu arreglo como por ejemplo [`array_push`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php)

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, le estaba dando vueltas y nada!  y claro tenia mal eso muchas gracias me funciono perfectamente! :)

Comment: @DiyermorenoHernández si la respuesta ha ayudado a resolver tu problema, considera marcarla como aceptada activando el cotejo gris a la izquierda de la misma.